# MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath number

Tags: java, json, mockmvc

I have serialized a ZonedDateTime as unix timestamp now i would like to check if the serialization worked. Therefore I did the following:

```
mockMvc.perform(get("/anyPath/"))
.andExpect(jsonPath("$.time", is(time.toEpochSecond())));
```

But this check fails because the Timestamp is serialized with nine digits after the dot. ie `1824379112.000000000` and this does not seem to match `w1StartTime.toEpochSecond()`. I tried to convert the value I handed over to the `is()` function to serveral different types including String, BigDecimal, double, Double, etc.

What do I have to do to match the serialized number?

Comment: You can try hamcrest matcher [IsCloseTo](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/number/IsCloseTo.html)